# In Firebase do I setup my 404 page

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

In Firebase do I setup my 404 page?

I have a Angular2 typescript app with routes.

My apps live and works fine. I want to create a 404 page just in case.

I have a route called /404 that I want to use.

How do I wire this 404 page component to Firebase?
Please add any examples of how I would do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's nothing Firebase special..

Just add a route like this:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
```

at the **bottom** of your route-array.

Expecting you have a route like this:

```
{ path: '404', component: Your404Component }
```

Comment: Thanks il try this

Answer (score 1):

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-404):

> **Custom 404/Not Found page**
>
> You can specify a custom 404/Not Found error to be served when a user tries to access a page that does not exist. Simply add a `404.html` page to the your project's public directory and the contents of this page will be displayed when Firebase Hosting needs to display a 404 Not Found error to the user.

Note that this is the first result I got when [searching for 'firebase hosting 404'](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=firebase%20hosting%20404).

Comment: That won't work, cause when hosting Angular2-app all URLs will be redirected. You have to handle that with Angular's Router.

Comment: Good point. I'm going to leave the answer up as most people don't know about this feature, but indeed it may well not apply here.